# How do I setup wfetch to connect to an HTTPS site?

Tags: iis

I can neither open wfetch.hlp not find any resource which documents the setup of wfetch aside from articles on how to add headers and body.

I continually get the following output:
0x274d (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it): [sockslib]: Unable to connect.

I have set the connection -> Connect: https, Cipher: default, Client cent: none

I also tried -> Connect: https, Cipher: default, Client cent: valid (under the assumption that this will accept whatever certificate is there - if this assumption is correct, then possibly my answer has nothing to do with https and confirmation of this would serve as an appropriate answer to this question)
output of this is:
0x8009030d (The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized.) [slib]: Could not acquireCredentialsHandle / Failed to AcquireCredentials())

Comment: Why was the tools tag removed?  Did a Google search on WFETCH and second entry is:WFetch
technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778443(v=WS.10).aspx
Aug 22, 2005 · Introduces the WFetch tool, which is included in the IIS 6.0 Resource Kit Tools, and provides links to more information.